# Puma produces error on start says its running but cannot be accessed via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I have a Rails 4.2.6 API running Puma on production and it failed after latest push. Reverted to a previously working commit but now have an error on start up even though the process is running on the server.

```
[1854] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[1854] * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
[1854] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
[1854] * Environment: production
[1854] * Process workers: 1
[1854] * Preloading application

THE ERROR---> /home/appname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/puma: No such file or directory -

[1854] * Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:8080?
 key=/home/appname/appname_react/sslforfree/private.key&cert=/home/appname/appname_react/sslforfree/certificate.crt
[1854] * Daemonizing...
```

The file definitely exists and appears to be fine.

/home/appname/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/puma:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin$ cat puma
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'puma' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first
str = ARGV.first
str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
 end
end

load Gem.bin_path('puma', 'puma', version)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was not the actual issue. In fact this "Error" is still printing during Puma start up but not affecting the API at all. 
The real issue was that when I reverted to previous commit that commit had an old password to the database and THAT was the actual issue I was having.

I found it by looking through the  puma_stdout.log  file on the production box.

```
 nano puma_stdout.log
```

Standing on my own shoelaces again.... :-)